# wpa_supplicant returns CTRL-EVENT-CONNECTED, but can't ping anything (ip: either "to" is duplicate, or "192.168.2.1" is garbage)

Tags: linux, networkmanager, wpa-supplicant

Heyo! I'm currently working on a from-scratch linux distro (not from LFS). I've gotten `wpa_supplicant` up and running, and `wpa_supplicant -Dnl90211 -iwlan0 -c/etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf` returns "key negotiated", and CTRL-EVENT-CONNECTED (id=0). So far so good?

So I open up another tty and run `ping 8.8.8.8`. Nada - I get `ping: sendto: Network is unreachable`. Well, ok. I run `ip route`, and get no response. Ok, easy peasy, just add a route! I run `ip route add default 192.168.2.1`, and bam: `ip: either "to" is duplicate, or "192.168.2.1" is garbage`. If I ping that on another machine, or on the same machine on another distro, I get valid responses.

I haven't install NetworkManager on this, that *could* be a problem. I admit that I have little experience with `wpa_supplicant` in general ;).

Thanks in advance!

[`dmesg PasteBin`](https://pastebin.com/Yg8CYnfe)

Comment: Try `ip route add default via 192.168.2.1`.

Comment: @JohanMyréen `ip: RTNETLINK answers: Network is unreachable`